# Android: How to use my custom IME only in my Application?

Tags: android, ime

I have made an IME depend on Google's SoftKeyboard Sample. But while I set it as my System default IME, the other APP also user it, My custom IME is not friendly to other APP. I only want to use it in my APP, is there any good advice?